# Notepad++: Edited and saved gnuplot script is not read properly

Tags: notepad++, gnuplot

When *editing* and saving a gnuplot script in Notepad++ (on Windows, obviously) and then immidiatly executing it, I almost always get error messages about crazy syntax errors that don't exist in the script. The solution is simple: In Notepad++, copy all -> delete all -> paste all -> save. Now, gnuplot can read it.

The weird thing is that I don't have similar issues with any other software: Writing HTML, PHP, JavaScript, normal text, all works fine!

Edit: Wrong, I just had an issue with a WSL bash script as well.

I'm hoping someone here has a deeper understanding of what's going on under the hood of either Notepad++ or gnuplot, since I'm not sure where the issue is. I suspect Notepad++, because it can be fixed from there, but what the nature of the problem is, I cannot fathom.

Comment: Is the script located on your local drive or on a network share? How large is the script and how long does saving take?

Comment: @Robert it's on a local SSD, the scripts are usually below 100 lines and saving is immediate

Comment: Could that be an encoding problem? Even though error messages look crazy, it'd be helpful to copy-paste a couple of examples.

Comment: @Joce I don't think so. The document reads fine, I make a minor change, shit happens. Copy, delete, paste and it's fine again. And it also really doesn't matter what code it is, anything works

Comment: Still, next time I get the error I'll post code and error message